# JSONP 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to get some API Data returned as JSON

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=london&format=json&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?callback=?';

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

xxxx being the api key, However I am getting the error 403 (Forbidden)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the key is wrong

Comment: Why did you title it JSONP? and not just JSON?

Comment: the key is correct - i can access it by inputing the url directly to the browser

Comment: because i need JSONP to avoid cross origin security

Comment: Try to call `setAttribute('src', ...)` instead of `script.src`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how much you've changed the url in your question from what's in your actual code, but you have "?callback=?" which I think should be "&callback=[some_function]". Seems like without the ampersand, it is seeing your key as "xxxxxxxxx?callback=?", which is incorrect, so it is denying you access.